# DATEPART FROM in T/SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

It appears that the following SQL is valid in *some* but not all versions of SQL Server 2019 (my local instance is v15.0.2000.5, and it fails, but around 15.0.2095 it succeeds):

`SELECT DATEPART(HOUR FROM DATEADD(HOUR, -4, GETDATE()))`

There appears to be no documentation around this - specifically the use of `FROM` where I expect a comma to be. Is this a new extension of the SQL language (and if so, why??), something that has crept in that may disappear again without warning, a bug, something that SSMS silently rewrites to something else...?

Comment: The above syntax does not work for me on 16.0.1000.6, but it does on  15.0.4223.1; I feel like this might be a bug, if I am honest (and that it *should not* work).

Comment: Why are you using 15.0.2000.5 still though? 15.0.2095 is at least the latest GDR version of SQL Server, however, there have been multiple bug fixes in 2019's CU's; is there are reason you haven't installed any of those? 15.0.2000.5  is the RTM version though; you really shouldn't be using that as there's over 3 years of security fixes you're missing.

Comment: @Larnu We run a wide variety of different versions in order to reproduce problems experienced in turn by our customers (who themselves regularly skip installing updates). They are not used by us in production scenarios.

Comment: Note, as well, this problem has nothing to do with SSMS; it isn't what parses the code.

Comment: I didn't expect so, but after much head-scratching I was prepared for anything to be possible!

Comment: FWIW, you can log bugs [here](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/forum/04fe6ee0-3b25-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0).

Answer (score 1):

As this behaviour does not exist in SQL Server 2022 or the docs it looks like a bug to me.

Maybe something went wrong with adding `FROM` to the allowed grammar with [`TRIM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) and it just ends up allowing it in additional places on those builds (?)

```
SELECT CHARINDEX ( 'A'  FROM 'ABCD')
```

also works.

At least the `FROM` keyword kind of makes sense with that and the `DATEPART` example but it makes no sense at all below (FROM just seems to be allowed in place of a comma there as long as only two items are being concatenated)

```
SELECT CONCAT ( 'Foo' FROM 'Bar')
```

Similarly

```
SELECT ROUND (1.23 FROM 1)
```

also works (as `ROUND(1.23,1)`)

My suspicion is that on these lucky builds any built in function that accepts two arguments can likely have the comma replaced with a `FROM`.

(above tests on 15.0.2095.3)